# Switching views in a tabpanel in Sencha Touch from a segmented button

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I have an application created with Sencha Touch 2, I need to create a card layout with different views switched with a segmented button, (Following MVC concept) but It is not working..

My view:

```
config: {
    layout: 'vbox',
    items : [
      {
        xtype: 'header'
      },
      {
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: 'card',
        items: [
          {
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'vbox',
            itemId: 'presence',
            items: [
              {
                xtype: 'surveyHeaderBrands'
              },
              {
                xtype: 'surveyEditorMatrix',
                flex : 1
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'vbox',
            itemId: 'auxiliaryFields',
            items: [
              {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'button'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'vbox',
            itemId: 'profiles',
            items: [
              {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'button2'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'vbox',
            itemId: 'photos',
            items: [
              {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'button3'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

In the controller I don´t know what code should be the correct.. I have tested with `this.control` etcetera but It is not working... any clue, please!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I added 'flex:1' to the main container and now it is working..

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can add ID to card container and then use setActiveItem on segmented button listener

> `Ext.getCmp("yourcardcontainerid").setActiveItem()`

Example:

```
    {
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: 'card',
        id: 'mynewid',
        items: [
          {
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'vbox',
            itemId: 'presence',
            items: [
              {
                xtype: 'surveyHeaderBrands'
              },
              {
                xtype: 'surveyEditorMatrix',
                flex : 1
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'vbox',
            itemId: 'auxiliaryFields',
            items: [
              {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'button'
              }
            ]
          },
        ]
    }
```

then in your segmented button

```
xtype: 'button',
handler: function()
{
    Ext.getCmp("mynewid").setActiveItem(1);
}
```

Definitely this is not the perfect answer since we are not using controller but it solve the problem.